# ElasticSearch: How to disable shard reallocation of all shards?

Tags: elasticsearch

I developed a search plugin for elasticsearch, but when upgrading this plugin, i need to shutdown the nodes one by one, and each time i have to wait for the reallocation process a long time. 
In the document, it said the reallocation process can be stopped by:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_cluster/settings -d '{
    "transient" : {
           "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "none"
     }
}'
```

When I run this command, i got following error:

```
ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[Can't update non dynamic settings[[index.transient.cluster.routing.allocation.enable]] for open indices[..]
```

What can i do?

btw:
sorry for my poor english...

Answer (score 7):

So close!

Try:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_cluster/settings' -d '{
"transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.disable_allocation": "true"
}}'
```

Comment: Also failed. It told me index _cluster does not exists.  And if i use _all, the same error is returned. My elasticsearch edition is 1.4.

Comment: Are you sure you PUT and didn't POST?

Comment: On elasticsearch 6.4 I'm seeing `{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}`

Comment: The new name of this setting is: cluster.routing.allocation.enable

<code>
    Enable or disable allocation for specific kinds of shards:

    all - (default) Allows shard allocation for all kinds of shards.
    primaries - Allows shard allocation only for primary shards.
    new_primaries - Allows shard allocation only for primary shards for new indices.
    none - No shard allocations of any kind are allowed for any indices.

Answer (score 1):

OP might use an older Elasticsearch version that doesn't support 
updating "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" and/or "cluster.routing.rebalance.enable" dynamically.

However, on more recent Elasticsearch versions, those 2 settings should
be `dynamic` or `transient`, not `static` or `persistent` any more.

Here are more details about shards-allocation settings from  Elasticsearch current doc.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/shards-allocation.html

And user can apply/revoke these settings in Kibana Dev Tool Console, like these

```
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "none",
    "cluster.routing.rebalance.enable" : "none"
  }
}

# After bouncing ES cluster
PUT _cluster/settings
{
  "transient" : {
    "cluster.routing.allocation.enable": "all",
    "cluster.routing.rebalance.enable" : "all"
  }
}
```