# Elasticsearch - timeout when deleting index

Tags: elasticsearch

i have cluster in red status and heap size is almost full...i need delete some index but i have a timeout error

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"process_cluster_event_timeout_exception","reason":"failed to process cluster event (delete-index [my.index-2016.08.01]) within 30s"}],"type":"process_cluster_event_timeout_exception","reason":"failed to process cluster event (delete-index [my.index-2016.08.01]) within 30s"},"status":503}
```

I can delete index in red status?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved disabling shard allocation, i could erase indexes, just finished, i reactivated allocation

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion to disable shard allocations helped with a cluster that was taking more than 1 minute to delete a single index. [Here's how to disable shard allocation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29432688/641451).

Answer (score 7):

What if you try and increase your `master_timeout` value within your request itself?

> curl -XDELETE yourhost:9200/index?master_timeout=60s

These threads could help you:

- [Ref 1](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/es-fails-to-delete-index/52757)
- [Ref 2](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/failed-to-delete-index-using-curator/18664)

Comment: `Truthfully, though, a delete operation that takes longer than even 3
seconds is indicative of an overloaded cluster.` Doesn't this imply "sort out your overloaded cluster rather than just increase the timeout (10-fold in you suggestion)"?

Comment: I have already tried with timeout but have same proeblem. The cluster is overloaded just because there are too many indexes and have to delete them...

Answer (score 1):

I tried with timeout but it didn't work, my issues resolved with retry.